# choosing a range from the data without missing the dimension in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

I have an array and I want to select a range from the data. The dataset is in twi array, the min value is 0 and maximum is 26.

I converted my data set from raster to array `twi_raster` to `twi_array`.

```
 twi_array = arc.RasterToNumPyArray(twi_raster , nodata_to_value=0)
 x= twi_array>9 and twi_array<=17
 twi_array = [ twi_array if x else 0 for x in twi_array]
```

I would like to select the range of my interest, however I failed because my `if` condition is wrong.

```
x= twi_array>9 and twi_array<=17
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the list of values in twi_array that are greater that are >9 and <= 17?

Comment: I am trying to get the set of values in the range of 9 to 17 only and make the rest of the array to zero

Comment: Your list comprehension seems a bit strange.  `twi_array = [x if x > 9 and x <= 17 else 0 for x in twi_array]` or just `twi_array = [x if x > 9 and x <= 17 for x in twi_array]`.

Comment: I just want to be clear x is my condition it is not the array twi_array

Comment: @apex-meme-lord do I have to set x= twi_array

Answer (score 0):

I might have confused you further by mixing concepts in my answer, so let me break it down for you.  This is the most faithful answer to your question:

```
twi_array = arc.RasterToNumPyArray(twi_raster , nodata_to_value=0)
x = lambda foo: foo > 9 and foo <= 17
twi_array = [bar if x(bar) else 0 for bar in twi_array]
```

`x` is defined as a lambda function which is functionally the same as:

```
def x(foo):
   return foo > 9 and foo <= 17
```

We use `bar if x(bar) else 0` as the python ternary operator
which is equivalent to:

```
if x(bar):
    bar
else:
    0
```

`bar` is defined only in the scope of the list comprehension (i.e., within the `[...]`).  We use it to iterate over the elements of `twi_array`

Comment: is this going to change the dimension of my array ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    
       twi_array = [bar if x(bar) else 0 for bar in twi_array]
      line 93, in <lambda>
      x = lambda foo: foo > 9 and foo <= 17
       ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one  element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: The list comprehension operator is only suitable for 1-dimension arrays.  If you need to apply this across an n-dimension array, you would probably want to [create a numpy vectorized function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) using the lambda.